# UdpClient C# BeginReceive from a specific EndPoint

Tags: c#, udp, ip, communication

I'm using UdpClient in my simple Udp Server.
is it possible to BeginReceive() only from a specific ip address?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  That's pretty fundamental about UDP, it is not a connection-oriented protocol like TCP.  You could only reject packets when you receive them by checking the IPEndPoint you get when you call EndReceive().  The odds that you'd actually have to do so ought to be quite small.